# Change wrapper tag when using justify

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using ckeditor 4 and when I trying to justify text http://prntscr.com/iq2l8g

it's wrapping in div.

```
<div text-align="align-direction">TEXT</div>
```

How can I change it's wrapper to `<p text-align="align-direction">TEXT</p>?`
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try online sample - https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fullpreset.html (please remove all the data, type few characters and try to justify the text) you will notice that once you have justified and switched to source mode, there is a `P` and not the `DIV`.

I will make a guess that you are using [enterMode](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-enterMode) set to `DIV` instead of `P` thus you are seeing such result. Justify plugin itself doesn't change tags. It only adds classes to existing tags.

Comment: Yeap, thanks. I found the problem. It's `entermode`- just need to use `CKEDITOR.ENTER_P`